# block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor

I've [read](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) that there is an option to make a blocking call using Mono.
So I tried to write several code snippets:

**A)**

```
Mono.just("qwerty")
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
.block()
```

**B)**

```
Mono<String> customMono = Mono.just("qwerty");
Mono<String> blockedMono = customMono
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
System.out.println("blockedMono.block(): " + blockedMono.block());
```

**C)**

```
 Mono<String> customMono = Mono.just("qwerty");
 Mono<String> blockedMono =  Mono.just(0)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .then(customMono);    
 System.out.println("blockedMono.block(): " + blockedMono.block());
```

leads to the same error:

```
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-1
```

Is there way to fix it ?

**P.S.** I need a blocking call and I am aware that it is not good to use blocking operations in reative code

**P.S.2**

This works but I want to avoid converting to Future

```
Mono.just("qwerty").toFuture().get()
```

**P.S.3**

As @dan1st noticed the behaviour depends on execution context.

1. All those code snippets works without any exceptions if we put them to the main method
2. The behaviour described in the topic is experienced if we put the code inside

   ```
   @GetMapping(..)
   public void someEndpoint(...) {
      // snippet is here
   }
   ```

So this behaviour depends on spring web flux somehow

Could you please clarify why and how to fix it ?

### UPDATE

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75096742/2674303) I was able to write the code block below. As a result this line doesn't throw any exception but it returns `null`.

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt jwt = it.block();
```

---

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Mono<org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt> test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Mono<org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt> firstMono =
            ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) //<-- this allows .block() somewhere downstream
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                    .flatMap(securityContext -> Mono.just((org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()));
    Mono<org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt> secondMono = Mono.just(firstMono)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map(it -> {
                org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt jwt = it.block();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + "-" + jwt);
                return jwt;
            });
    return secondMono;
}
```

So endpoint method fails with error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper [....my.Controller$$Lambda$2012/0x0000000800b68840] returned a null value
```

But if I write

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Mono<org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt> test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Mono<org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt> firstMono =
            ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .map(securityContext ->(org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal());        
    return firstMono;
}
```

everything is OK and response contains JWT. Looks like it is because of spring webflux context magic.

Comment: Isn't this a continuation of your earlier question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75055071/how-to-make-blocking-call-for-monohow-to-get-token-from-reactivesecuritycontex?

Comment: continuation but not duplication!
It is a thumbnail rule to create separated topic for a new question

Comment: What created the thread your code is running in? Does it work outside of Reactor threads?

Comment: @dan1st it is written just inside the main method

Comment: Possible answer to your question : [how to use block() operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549756/2678097)

Comment: @dan1st Sorry - my previous comment was wrong. So you was right - behaviour depends on context. I updated topic. Could you please provide more details in the answer.

Comment: @amanin I tried different options but I was not able to get the expected result. I will appreciated if you could provide the single working option which allow me to make a blocking call.

Comment: Is it possible to create a new thread in the endpoint and block in that thread (the endpoint seems to return `void` in your example)?

Comment: @dan1st let me try

Comment: @dan1st I've shared experiments results here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062475/reactivesecuritycontextholder-returns-null-in-case-of-blocking-operations

Comment: Note that `join()`ing the thread in a reactive method is a bad idea - it's best to not block there at all.

Comment: @dan1st It is just for experimental purposes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Disclaimer

This is a rephrase and clarification of [my answer from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549756/2678097).

### Blocking in Reactor

When you block in reactor, it means the thread calling `block()` is locked, waiting for the block operation to end.

One important fact is that the blocked thread is the *calling thread, not one of the thread of the publisher*. It might look like an obvious statement, but I've been bitten by this error in the past, and many other users also (this is the subject of your question, for example).

As *block* is **not** part of the reactive pipeline, when you do this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Mono.just(1000)
       .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
       .flatMap(delay -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(delay)) // <1>
       .block(); // <2>
}
```

1. *flatMap* is executed by *single* scheduler
2. *block*   is executed by program main thread.

And when you do this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var publisher = Mono.just(1000)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .flatMap(delay -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(delay));
   
    Mono.just("whatever")
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .map(it -> publisher.block()) // <1>
        .block(); // <2>
}
```

1. The first block is executed on a thread of the *bounded elastic* scheduler.
2. The second block is executed from program main thread.

### When blocking is forbidden

To discourage its usage, Reactor enforce context verification. When `block()` is called, it checks what is the calling thread, and if it consider the calling thread comes from a *blocking incompatible scheduler*, it will raise an error, to prevent locking the thread.

**Most** of Reactor and Webflux schedulers are **incompatible** with `block()`, because they are designed for high throughput using minimal resource.

Therefore, when you return a publisher containing block operations in webflux, most of the time it will be executed in a scheduler that do not accept it, and you end up with the error you describe.

### How to block in the middle of a reactive pipeline

First and foremost, try to avoid blocking. Verify if this is avoidable. Otherwise:

1. Select a blocking compatible scheduler:

   - The only one I know in "standard" schedulers is [the bounded elastic scheduler](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#boundedElastic--)
   - Another solution is to create your own Scheduler. For example, you can [wrap a java Executor Service](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#fromExecutorService-java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService-java.lang.String-)
2. **Wrap** the publisher you want to block with another one, that will publish / schedule its actions on your scheduler:

   ```java
   Scheduler blockingCompatibleScheduler = Schedulers.boundedElastic();
   Mono<T> toBlock = Mono...
   Mono<T> wrapper = Mono.fromCallable(() -> toBlock.block())
                         .subscribeOn(blockingCompatibleScheduler);
   // or
   Mono<T> wrapper = Mono.just("any")
                         .publishOn(blockingCompatibleScheduler)
                         .map(it -> toBlock.block());
   ```

   More details available in [dedicated section of the official doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

### Block breaks context

Until now, I was refering to the *execution* context. But there is a second kind: the
*state* context.

Since Reactor 3.1, a [Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/Context.html) / [ContextView](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/ContextView.html) API is provided to share contextual information across *chained* subscriptions, from downstream to upstream.

The official documentation contains an [dedicated section about this mechanism](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context), to provide in-depth explanation (this is quite complex).

Due to its nature, `block` operator prevent this mechanism to work.
As a context propagate information from a downstream subscription to an inner/upstream one, it cannot provide context information to `block` operator: it use a hidden subscription, disconnected from the parent/downstream subscription/pipeline. Said otherwise, a flux/mono cannot access an inner blocked publisher, and therefore cannot propagate context in it.

We can test it in a simplified example:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class BlockBreaksContext {

    static final Object CTX_KEY = new Object();

    /**
     * Add "Hello" message to the provided action context, then run/block it and print
     * output value.
     */
    static void execute(Mono<String> action) {
        String value = Mono.from(action)
                           .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(CTX_KEY, "Hello"))
                           .block();
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono<String> getContextValue = Mono.deferContextual(ctx
                -> Mono.just(ctx.getOrDefault(CTX_KEY, "No value from context")));

        // Without blocking, the mono will receive the context written by downstream subscription
        execute(getContextValue.map(it -> "NO BLOCKING: " + it));

        // With blocking, the Mono is **not** part of the "main" pipeline/subscription.
        // Therefore, it cannot receive context on execution, because block cause an
        // independent/isolated subscription, whose main chain of event is unaware of.
        Mono wrapBlock = Mono.fromCallable(() -> getContextValue.block());
        execute(wrapBlock.map(it -> "BLOCKING: " + it));
    }
}
```

This program prints:

```
NO BLOCKING: Hello
BLOCKING: No value from context
```

In your question, you try to access a security token. As the token is resolved upon client request, Webflux put it in the response publisher context. When you block, you disassociate your blocked publisher from the response publisher.

Comment: I've got an idea but I have an additional related question. Please read my topic update.

Comment: That's because there's an execution context (Scheduler API) and a *state* context (Context API). Blocking break both. I will try to edit my answer with more details later (when I've got a little spare time).

Comment: Thank you - will wait for update from your side.

Comment: kindly reminder

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that you would have been notified of the edit. I've edited my answer last friday. I've added a "Block breaks context" section at the end of my answer. It shows that `block` prevents access to the ContextView object.

Comment: oh...let me read...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I have cople of quetions although:
1. Does `block()` considered the same as `.toFuture.get()` ?

2. **Webflux put it in the response publisher context**
Where spring Webflux  stores it ? Is it possible to acces this from my code ?
I've created separated topic for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124144/what-spring-webflux-does-behind-the-scene-after-exit-from-endpoint-method-which