# Filter a Mono<T> with a String Id matching one of a list of Flux<String>

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm fetching a Mono (with T containing an `id` and `orgId` fields). I also have a Flux of orgIds. I need to return the Mono if T.getOrgId() is contained in the Flux.

I'm not entirely sure to understand the exact Mono/Flux flow. But so far I have tried 2 approaches, blocking and non-blocking.

Blocking

```
public Mono<T> getItemBlocking(final String orgId, final String id) {
        final Flux<String> orgs = getOrgs(orgId);
        final T t = repository.findById(id).block();
        final Boolean tInOrg = orgs.hasElement(t.getOrgId()).subscribe().isDisposed();
        return tInOrg ? repository.findById(id) : Mono.error(someError.error(id)); // Ideally would not make the request again
}
```

The code is not working, I'm receiving the following exception:

`"java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread  reactor-http-nio-4 at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83)`

Non-blocking

```
public Mono<T> getItemNonBlocking(final String orgId, final String id) {
        final Flux<String> orgs = getOrgs(orgId);
        return (Mono<T>) repository.findById(id)
                .filter(t -> orgs.hasElement(t.getOrgId()).block()) // Need to make this non blocking but I'm not able to, but need the Mono<Boolean> to be a Boolean
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(someError.error(id))
                .subscribe();
}
```

This code is not working also, I'm receiving the exception:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber incompatible with  reactor.core.publisher.Mono at service.getItemNonBlocking`

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should [avoid blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75096742/2678097). Blocking is designed for cases where you have to interact with non reactive components.
2. If you return a Mono, you should not subscribe yourself. It is the user/consumer that should do it.

Now, you can achieve what you want by modifying your second example:

1. Change *filter* with *filterWhen*, to allow a reactive stream as operator, instead of a blocking op.
2. Return the resulting reactive pipeline directly, instead of subscribing to it.

```java
return repository.findById(id)
                .filterWhen(t -> getOrgs(orgId).hasElement(t.getOrgId()))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(someError.error(id));
```