# spring boot webclient blocking not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

The following function:

```
public ScoringResponse search(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
    return webClient.post()
            .bodyValue(searchRequest)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, ERROR_HANDLER::handleError)
            .bodyToMono(ScoringResponse.class)
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5_000))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .block();
}
```

It return this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are
blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2
```

Comment: Right, you should not use `.block()` unless you're really understand what you're doing, and a Reactor watchdog prevents you from doing such a mistake

Comment: Here, subscribeOn will not help you. It does not impact block() call below. Your error means block() has been called from another reactive stream and it could have been avoided. We need more context about how this function is used to provide a good answer. Maybe you could avoid blocking, and if it cannot be avoided, we cannot provide the right solution without knowing the code calling it. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058585/block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking-which-is-not-supported-in-thread/75096742#75096742) can provide insight.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public Mono<ScoringResponse> search(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
return webClient.post()
        .bodyValue(searchRequest)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, ERROR_HANDLER::handleError)
        .bodyToMono(ScoringResponse.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5_000))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());                        
}
```